# REST request errors in Jquery but not REST Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, cookies, jira

I am trying to use the [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/) to preform some requests. One of the first things that you must do, according the docs, is authenticate in some way.

Atlassian offers 2 methods; [Basic Auth](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication) and [Cookie Based Auth](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-cookie-based-authentication), the later of which uses cookies to establish a `session`.

The issue comes into play when I involve Jquery/JS.

Here is the request when preformed in [ARC (Advanced Rest Client) for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US):

[image]

If I run that request, I will get a HTTP 200 response with the correct JSON, which is what I want.

However, when I attempt to do this with Jquery/JS, I recieve an error every time.

Here is that code:

```
            function cookieLogin() {
            //Grab username and password from the fields on the page
            var user = $("#loginUsername").val();
            var pass = $("#loginPassword").val();

            $.ajax({
                //URL
                url: baseURL + path,

                //Method
                //type: 'POST', //analogous to 'method'
                method: 'POST',

                //Headers
                accept: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                contentType: 'application/json',

                //Payload to be sent
                data:
                {
                    "username": "admin",
                    "password": "admin"
                },

                //Responses to HTTP status codes
                statusCode: {
                    200: function () {
                        alert("Success!");
                    },

                    401: function() {
                        alert("Invalid Credentials");
                    },

                    403: function () {
                        alert("Failed due to CAPTCHA requirement/throttling.")
                    }
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(result);
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error!!!");
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

I have assured that the URL is correct. As you can see, I also hard-coded the credentials (this is merely a test page) just to test as well. I'm not sure why I am receiving errors in JS when I replicated the same thing that worked in ARC.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), I am seeing that "accept" should be "accepts" and "dataType" takes the string "json", not "application/json".